# What is specifically incoherent in my code? even if the password is correct the login successful message is not outputted

Tags: mysql, authentication, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a login/sign up form using C++ and MySQL on Visual Studio 2019, despite the fact that the sign up works and actually stores the information the user inputs into the databse. While logging into the application, even if the password is correct, always the `"username or password is incorrect!\n try again..."`  is always outputted when running the application. I haven't tried much because I am not even able to see the error in the first place.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

        try
        {

            String^ constr = "Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=database";
            MySqlConnection^ con = gcnew MySqlConnection(constr);

            String^ password = textBox8->Text;
            String^ username = textBox1->Text;

            MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from register_table where Username='" + username + "' and Password='" + password + "';", con);
            MySqlDataReader^ dr;


            con->Open();
            try
            {
                dr = cmd->ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                while (dr->Read())
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox::Show("Login successful, Congratulations...");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox::Show("username or password is incorrect!\n try again...");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception^ ex)
            {
                MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
            }


            con->Close();


        }
        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Visual Studio has a best-of-breed debugger. Use it to step through your function so you can see exactly what the program is doing as it does it. You'll probably see exactly what went wrong and how to fix it. If not, what you learn will help you write a better question.

Comment: SQL injections **and** plain-text passwords? I really hope this isn't going to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, after debugging the application, I saw that for some reason it confused the password and username. So I just switched their places and it worked, in this way that is:

`MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("select * from register_table where Username='" + password + "' and Password='" + username + "';", con);`

Weird, but hey it works!